# PHP/MySQL string

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I'm trying to insert a value in a table from a textarea.

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO message_admin (message, lastedit_ip, lastedit_date) VALUES ('".$_POST["message"]."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".date("d/m/Y")."');";
```

Thing is if I type either the symbol ' or " in my text area, I will get PHP debug because PHP will take it as if I closed my string (is that the right expression, even?)
Hope you did understand me

Comment: You're right, PHP does see those characters as delimiters. Take the swearing out and try your question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addslashes()`

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO message_admin (message, lastedit_ip, lastedit_date) VALUES ('".addslashes($_POST["message"])."', '".addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', '".date("d/m/Y")."');";
```